# Проблема с логикой клеточного автомата

Tags: c++, windows-10

Я очень начинающий разработчик, и решил сделать клеточный автомат в консоли по типу WireWorld. Всё шло гладко и без багов, до того момента пока я не начал программировать логику игры.

```
void logicApply()
{
    int xlog = 1; int ylog = 1;
    while (ylog < height)
    {
        while (xlog < width)
        {
            if (map[ylog][xlog] = WIRE)
            {
                for (int b = -1; b <= 1; b++)
                {
                    for (int a = -1; a <= 1; a++)
                    {
                        if (map[ylog + b][xlog + a] == SOURCE || map[ylog + b][xlog + a] == WSWIRE)
                        {
                            map[ylog][xlog] = WSWIRE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xlog++;
        }
        ylog++;
    }
}
```

Здесь я написал логику только для клетки провода. Ожидание:
[image: Генератор передаёт сигнал]

Реальность:

[image: Что происходит?]

Почему код создаёт призрачные клетки сверху, на которые правильно действует логика, но на настоящие клетки нет?
Я 3 раза переписывал логику, но итог всегда один и тот-же.

Comment: `if(map[ylog][xlog] = WIRE)` - здесь безусловное присвоение. А если у вас `WIRE` равен нулю, то и весь код не будет выполнятся.

Comment: AlexGlebe, призрачные клетки исчезли, но клетки всё равно не взаимодействуют друг с другом

Comment: перед **каждым** проходом цикла `while (xlog < width){` нужно переменной присвоить начальное значение `xlog = 1 ; while (xlog < width){`

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.